# Port forwarding mosquitto on windows

Tags: networking, router, mqtt

I have set up a mosquitto broker on my laptop (with windows 10) using the first part of this tutorial. I subscribed to a topic and successfully published/received a message on the localhost, as explained in the tutorial. My next goal is to run the mosquitto server on my local machine, subscribe to a topic, and then publish to this topic using a different machine on a different network (over internet), and receive this message on my local machine.

Upon searching the internet, I found that port forwarding is what I am looking for. The image below shows my routers port-forwarding settings page

[Image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVkkr.jpg)

In section 1, I believe I have to enter the local IP address of the laptop which is running the mosquitto broker (right?)

In section 2, what should the starting and ending port should be?

In section 4, should "All IP addresses" be left checked?

Should I go ahead and disable the Firewall on my system?

Is there anything else I need to do to accomplish the task at hand? Am I missing something out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Section 1 you need to enter the IP Address the request is going to - so the device the server is running on.

The port must be either a range or a single one. Those are the ones defined in the config of the server software, via the entry `listener`. If it is a range, enter the first port number into the first field and the last port number in the second field.

If you have only one port to open, you can enter the same port into both fields, or just one port into the first, depending on how your router wants it. Mine only wants one field filled, if there is only one port, I know routers that always need both fields filled, so look into the manual please.

For the remote part, either leave "All IP Addresses" on or only enter the IP you want to connect to. Leave the protocol on TCP.

And no, never disable your firewall. This is always the wrong thought to have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what does the entries in the second port signify? Do they mean that any packet received by the router with these port numbers will be forwarded to that device which is running the server?

Comment: @KiranNisa It means you can use a range of ports. For example, 1500 in the first and 2000 in the second means you are opening 500 ports, all from 1500 to 2000.